# SQL Get string between second and third underscore

Tags: sql

I need to extract a certain string from a column in a table as part of an SSIS package.

The contents of the column is formatted like this "TST_AB1_ABC123456_TEST".

I need to get the string between the second and 3rd "_", e.g. "ABC123456" without changing too much of the package so would rather do it in 1 SQL command if possible.

I've tried a few different methods using SUBSTRING, REVERSE and CHARINDEX but can't figure out how to get just that string.

Comment: Can you share your example code?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own string functions...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the base string functions:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(col,
              CHARINDEX('_', col, CHARINDEX('_', col) + 1) + 1,
              CHARINDEX('_', col, CHARINDEX('_', col, CHARINDEX('_', col) + 1) + 1) -
                  CHARINDEX('_', col, CHARINDEX('_', col) + 1) - 1)
FROM yourTable;
```

In notes format, the above call to `SUBSTRING` is saying:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(<your column>,
              <starting at one past the second underscore>,
              <for a length of the number of characters in between the 2nd and 3rd
                   underscore>)
FROM yourTable;
```

On other databases, such as Postgres and Oracle, there are substring index and regex functions which can handle the above more gracefully.  Actually, more recent versions of SQL Server have a `STRING_SPLIT` function, which could be used here, but it does not maintain the order of the resulting parts.

Answer (score 1):

If your column values always have 4 parts you can use the [PARSENAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function like this.

```
DECLARE @MyString VARCHAR(100)

SET @MyString = 'TST_AB1_ABC123456_TEST';

SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@MyString, '_', '.'), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using `Cross Apply`. I added in a `where` clause to make sure you don't get an error resulting from strings without 3 underscores

```
with your_table as (select 'TST_AB1_ABC123456_TEST' as txt1)

select txt1, txt2
from your_table t1
where txt1 like '%_%_%_%'
cross apply (select charindex( '_', txt1) as i1) t2 -- locate the 1st underscore
cross apply (select charindex( '_', txt1, (i1 + 1)) as i2 ) t3 -- then the 2nd
cross apply (select charindex( '_', txt1, (i2 + 1)) as i3 ) t4 -- then the 3rd
cross apply (select substring( txt1,(i2+1), (i3-i2-1)) as txt2) t5 -- between 2nd & 3rd
```

**Outputs**

```
+------------------------+-----------+
|          txt1          |   txt2    |
+------------------------+-----------+
| TST_AB1_ABC123456_TEST | ABC123456 |
+------------------------+-----------+
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c0fa41a30748e544df5e3f8174dac8a8)**